# How do I write and encode my file in UTF-8 style in python?

Tags: python

```
import io

def write_ngrams(table, filename):

    with io.open(filename, "w") as file:
        for i in table:
            outputstring=(('%d %s\n' % (table[i], i)))
            encoded = outputstring.encode("utf-8")
            file.write(encoded)

tabel = ngram_table('hiep, hiep, hoera!', 3, 0) // these are not really interesting for now

write_ngrams(tabel, "testfile3.txt")
```

I am getting an error at the file.write(encoded) line that states the following:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes.
```

However my assignment was: The output must use the utf8 encoding,

Which means that the output should be in the form of b'....'

With the ways I have tried I only get the string without the encoding or the error. However when I use print(encoded) I do receive the output in UTF-8 encoding, however when I write it to a file the encoding is gone or I get an error.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: change `io.open(filename, "w")` to `io.open(filename, "wb")`. notice the `b` next to the `w`

Comment: Please don't deface your question

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've 

granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. 

By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know how to delete your post, take a 

look at [**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the string to `write()` & open the file with the encoding set to `utf-8`

```
import io

def write_ngrams(table, filename):

    with io.open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for i in table:
            outputstring=(('%d %s\n' % (table[i], i)))
            file.write(outputstring)

tabel = ngram_table('hiep, hiep, hoera!', 3, 0) // these are not really interesting for now

write_ngrams(tabel, "testfile3.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this did indeed fix my problem. However, when I open my .txt file I don't see the encoding myself. Is this supposed to be the case? (this is my first semester using Python so I am not really experienced with it yet)

Comment: The encoding is how characters are represented in bytes (ultimately everything is bytes). If you use any modern text editor, they will be able to handle utf-8 seamlessly. It's not something you can "see". You can try to check the encoding in the text editor metadata. For example, VS Code shows the encoding in the bottom right